# Using MultiDataTrigger to test for 0 and a boolean in TextBox which has StringFormat in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, formatting

I have a TextBox bound to a decimal value which I want to format to not display decimal values if they are zero. At the same time I want to change the Background to a color if the property value is zero and another boolean property is true.

I have managed to achieve both but not together. If I remove the `StringFormat` from the Text Binding below the Background works perfectly but a value of, for example, 10 is displayed as 10.00, which I don't want. With the `StringFormat` the Background is not set and the `TextBox` is empty when 0 and suppresses decimals if they are zero, as required (empty string for zero is acceptable). So I assume it has to do with the empty string. I did try to test for an empty string with `Path=Text.IsEmpty` and `value="True"` as suggested in another post but that gives a design time error that Property `IsEmpty` is not found on type String.

This is what I have so far:

```
    <TextBox x:Name="FactorValueTextBox" Text="{Binding Value, StringFormat={}{0:# ###.##}}" IsReadOnly="{Binding CommodityGradingFactor.Total}" GotKeyboardFocus="GradeFactorGotKeyboardFocus">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=Text}" Value="0"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding CommodityGradingFactor.Manditory}" Value="True"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightPink"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                        <Condition Property="IsReadOnly" Value="False"/>
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                </MultiTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

For completeness the `GotKeyboardFocus()` function simply selects the current value when the user tabs into the `TextBox`:

```
private void GradeFactorGotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyboardDevice.IsKeyDown(Key.Tab))
        ((TextBox)sender).SelectAll();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of binding the condition to the property `Text`

```
<Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=Text}" Value="0"/>
```

Why not binding it to the property `Value`

```
<Condition Binding="{Binding Value}" Value="0"/>
```

Note:

Depending on your use case, you may want to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged)  on your `Value` property, avoid naming your backfield property as "value" since it is a [Contextual keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/)
 for `INotifyPropertyChanged` case.

Comment: The simplest solution is sometimes staring you right in the face. The Note you added on avoiding using `Value` as a Backfield property was also particularly useful. Besides the potential conflict with `INotifyPropertyChanged` it also has potential to create confusion when reading code. Thanks for that and for providing the link!

Comment: indeed @"The simplest solution is sometimes staring you right in the face", you're welcome glad it was useful.